# Beginner Question: How to automate desk allocation

Tags: python, excel

I am not sure whether this is the right place, but I have my first project and don't know where to begin. I want to get into data science/ practical programming and a family friend gave me my first real project, but I don't W where to start, please point me in the right direction.

Their growing company has recently embraced hot-desking, which is currently being managed manually in an excel spreadsheet. The hope is to automate this process such that one can input staff leave and get it a desk allocation, given a current floorplan and preferred clustering of teams.

I am so overwhelmed that I am not sure what tool to use. The most direct approach with minimal disruption to their day to day I can see is as follows:

a python program that reads a spreadsheet with staff availability/leave and outputs desk allocation in a similar format as their current solution. However, I am still not sure how to start there.

Hope you can help me see the first through the trees,

A confused newbie.

Comment: Welcome! This question seems to have a couple sub questions: maybe you could clarify and start with askng "What is the best mathematical model for this problem?" before developing a program.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.